# Can I prioritize post categories for choice for breadcrumb trail?

Tags: categories, breadcrumb

I'm using `Breadcrumb NavXT` for displaying breadcrumbs trail of given page, based on category tree.

This works fine half of the time - the problem is I (ab)use categories to assign specific properties to given pages, which are then interpreted in post.php to render given post in a specific way, e.g. hide the title or format in a specific way. And `Breadcrumb NavXT` sometimes picks these "meta-categories" to render the breadcrumbs, instead of the main category.

Is there a neat way to either get the plugin to include/exclude certain category trees, or make given categories "preferred" or replace the plugin altogether with something that would handle the problem better?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin [represents a fair bit of code to read through](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/breadcrumb-navxt/trunk) but I did not see any obvious way to prioritize/eliminate/ignore categories in the way you want.

I would suggest that you stop abusing categories and convert your code to use post meta (probably) instead of categories to " to assign specific properties to given pages".